# ids collision in android xmls

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have 3 xml views, but all of them has a view with the same name:

`@+id/userNameTitle`

how does the java code knows which field to edit when this line is executed?

`((TextView)findViewById(R.id.userNameTitle)).setText(Data.mUserName);`

according to the line in the `OnCreate`?

`setContentView(R.layout.myXml);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findViewById` look's for a view with the id in the current inflated layout.

So if you have this `setContentView(R.layout.myXml)` and  `findViewById(R.id.userNameTitle)` it looks for a view with id `userNameTitle` in `myxml.xml`.

For more info check the topic under ID in the below link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Note : Any View object may have an integer ID associated with it, to uniquely identify the View within the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Use the View inflatet and call `View.findViewById(id)` on that view